# BOOTSTRAP v3.3.5 responsive breakpoint and logo

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new using css & bootstrap.

I am having problems how to fix this error:

**1. If the App width is more than 973px the navbar looks great:**
[image]

**2. If the App width is less than 900px, the navbar change the style and also looks great:**

[image]

**3. But when the width is between 900px and 973px the logo and the rest of the elements in the navbar are staked like this:**

[image]

So I understand that this is something to do with the logo and how I manage the responsive breakpoints.
And this breakpoints are made by bootstrap and they looks ok:
The separate `@media (min-width:901px)` & `@media (max-width:900px)`.

So I dont know how to fix this responsive stacked elements.

Information:

- I am using Bootstrap v.3.3.5

Comment: You don't need to make it responsive on every single pixel, I mean like there are specific breakpoints that includes (_desktops, ipads, tablets, mobiles, etc ..._), but if you feel that this thing is very important to you, add `@media (min-width:900px) and (max-width: 973px)`, then decrease the logo `width` and maybe `font-size`,`margin` and `padding` for the buttons. change their values to make them fit your desires (**Make sure all of these changes are written under the media query**)

Comment: Or you can merge buttons that have common use into a dropdown, another solution is to make the menu collapse at `973px`

Comment: Thanks!!!! I will try the first one you told me, seems very smart!

Comment: If you want me to suggest a solution from above, the last solution I would go with is the one you chose, for me, I prefer to (_merge buttons that have common use into a dropdown, or to make the menu collapse at `973px`_)